# How do i set row height in a table?

Tags: python, pdf, borb

I'm using the python library [borb](https://pypi.org/project/borb/) to create a PDF document.

I want to set the row height in a table. If i use

```py
TableCell(paragraph, preferred_width=Decimal(150), preferred_height=Decimal(200))
```

in a `FlexibleColumnWidthTable`, the width-value will be used, but the height is ignored.

Is there another way to set the height of table rows?

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer** I am the author of the library you are using.

I would recommend you issue a bug ticket on the GitHub repository. `TableCell` is meant to take into account the preferences.

It may decide not to do when layout becomes impossible.

As an interim measure, you can wrap your `LayoutElement` objects in a custom object (created by you) that always returns the desires dimensions in its `get_content_box` methods.